# How to trigger email through MobilePush SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to send a Welcome email immediately after a user registers to my mobile application. 
Once a user registers, a unique identifier is created for them. We have their email on file and it will be stored in the data warehouse but I would like this data to be pushed directly from the application to Marketing Cloud so that I can send a real-time email.

What approach should I take to get this email sent out to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You should set an Attribute from the SDK which will result in the contact record being updated.  From there you can create an automation/data extension that monitors the value of the aforementioned attribute and have that trigger the welcome e-mail.

Android: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#attributes

iOS: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html#attributes

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this- so I'd have to add the attributes through Contact Builder (i.e. at MobilePush Demographics), but I can't directly access this as a data extension. The only way I can view a contact's attributes is if I go through MobilePush and drill down to that specific contact. How do I go about writing an automation that looks for this attribute?

Comment: You should contact professional services through your success/account manager.